# Button from an activity overlapping a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, button

I have an activity with buttons and text fields and more stuff, And in that activity one of the buttons opens a fragment dynamically on top of the activity:

```
    btnGate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            sgFrag = new SetGateFragment();
            fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.container,sgFrag);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

In this fragment I also have a few buttons. Now, when I tested my app on my phone to check if all the buttons in the activity as well as the buttons in the fragment are working everything worked fine, I was able to click the buttons in the activity as well as the buttons in the fragment and they all correspondent accordingly, but then I decided to test my app on galaxy note5 , and this time when I clicked the button to open the fragment one of the buttons from the activity overlapped the fragment and was clickable while neither of the buttons in the fragment were clickable.
Wasn't sure what could be the cause , Here is the fragment opening tag:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.phonegate.SetGateFragment"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundfrag"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1" />
```

Here is my activitys layout opening tag:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.phonegate.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:id = "@+id/container"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..!

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
SetGateFragment fragment = new SetGateFragment();
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_contenier,fragment).commit();
```